# Replacing specific columns with Y as 1 and N as 0

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with many columns that has "Y" and "N". So I am trying to create a function so that "Y" is replaced with 1 and "N" is replaced with 0. But not all columns need to replaced but only few.

```
res
ColA     ColB   ColC    ColD    ColE
   A       Y    N        Y       N
   B       N    N        N       N
   A       N             N       Y 
   B       Y    Y        N       Y
```

So basically, we can replace with below code. But we have to repeat many times.

```
res$ColB <- ifelse(res$ColB == "Y",1,ifelse(res$ColB == "N", 0 , NA))
```

Can we create a function like below so that once we pass arguments as column names, the function should take care. Example like below (not working)

```
binary_format <- function(df, x,...){
  df$x <- ifelse(df[[x == "Y",1,ifelse(df$x == "N", 0 , NA))
  return(df)
}
```

Expected output

```
binary_format(res, ColB, ColC)
ColA     ColB   ColC    ColD    ColE
   A       1    0        Y       N
   B       0    0        N       N
   A       0             N       Y 
   B       1    1        N       Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
dat <- read.table(header=T, text = "ColA     ColB   ColC    ColD    ColE
#    A       Y    N        Y       N
#    B       N    N        N       N
#    A       N    .        N       Y 
#    B       Y    Y        N       Y")
binary_format <- function(x, nms) {
  x[,nms] <- lapply(x[,nms], function(z) c(N = 0L, Y = 1L)[z])
  x
}
binary_format(dat, c("ColB", "ColC"))
#   ColA ColB ColC ColD ColE
# 1    A    1    0    Y    N
# 2    B    0    0    N    N
# 3    A    0   NA    N    Y
# 4    B    1    1    N    Y
```

Alternatively,

```r
binary_format <- function(x, ...) {
  nms <- unlist(list(...))
  x[,nms] <- lapply(x[,nms], function(z) c(N = 0L, Y = 1L)[z])
  x
}
binary_format(dat, "ColB", "ColC")
```

It is feasible to use NSE (non-standard evaluation) to be able to use non-quoted names, though if your only purpose is code-golf then I recommend against this. Having said that,

```r
binary_format <- function(x, ...) {
  nms <- as.character(substitute(alist(...)))[-1]
  x[, nms] <- lapply(x[, nms], function(z) c(N = 0L, Y = 1L)[z])
  x
}
binary_format(dat, ColB, ColC)
#   ColA ColB ColC ColD ColE
# 1    A    1    0    Y    N
# 2    B    0    0    N    N
# 3    A    0   NA    N    Y
# 4    B    1    1    N    Y
```